# JQuery window print feature issue

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, printing, window

I create one paper width 21.0 cm height 29.7cm but when i print the page printer give me three paper. I dont know what is my mistake. But i create just two paper.

the source code there

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9mh1dx/7/

```
window.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```html
<div id="Icerik" style="padding:0.5cm;width:28.7cm ;height:19.9cm ;">
```

Appears to work...

Comment: Can confirm: the div seems to be too big. If one reduces the height a bit it works: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9mh1dx/13/